# Is there any method like "popoverPresentationControllerWillDismissPopover"

Tags: ios, popover, uipopover

There is only 1 method about dissmissing the popover in `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`, which named "popoverPresentationController**Did**DismissPopover".

I am making some UI update in this method. However,it would spend a little time to dismissing the popover.

Is there any way to make my UI updates before the popover is get dismissed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this delegate method,

```
func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool
```

and return YES by default, this will be called before the pop over gets dismissed, I mean before the animation happens.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, it's very helpful!